# Google Scholar API of SerpApi fetches only first 100 articles from GoogleScholar profile

Tags: php, laravel, google-scholar, serpapi

**What am I trying to do ?**
I am trying to use **SerpApi's** **Google Scholar API** for fetching articles of the publishers and was expecting all article titles to store in the array `$title` but it limits only to the first 100 articles.

**Any Help Would be really appreciated, code :**

**title.py**

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import sys

id = sys.argv[1]
key = sys.argv[2]
params = {
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "author_id": id,
  "api_key": key,
  "sort":"pubdate",
  "num":10000
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
articles = results["articles"]

res = [ sub['title'] for sub in articles ]

print(res)
```

**Controller**

```
$title = shell_exec("python publicationScripts/title.py $gscID $key");
dd($title);
```

**Output**

```
The output shows only 100 articles but there are more than 200 articles
```

Comment: Hey Ana :) This is expected as you haven't applied pagination. In your example, you're iterating over `articles` and extracting `title`. Here's how you would do pagination in Python: https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-all-google-scholar-profile-author-results-with-python-and-serpapi/#author_article_results. Additionally, [`num`](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api#api-parameters-pagination-num) has a maximum of 100 results per page. It cannot display more than that. It's a Google restriction.

Answer (score 0):

> This is expected as you haven't applied pagination. In your example, you're iterating over articles and extracting title. Here's how you would do pagination in Python.
>
> Additionally, [num has a maximum of 100 results per page](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api#api-parameters-pagination-num). It cannot display more than that. It's a Google restriction

Thank you to [Dmitriy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040433/google-scholar-api-of-serpapi-fetches-only-first-100-articles-from-googlescholar#comment132476759_75040433) for clarification. You can get more than 100 by using pagination.